# how to set Error on truncation in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I'm just new in the informatica and I want to set a data loading that will handle error checking.

E.g I have char(1) data type in the Recepction Table now, in my source I have more than 1 char but informatica is loading the data and it is being truncated in the reception table.

I just want configure the loading that my session will fail if there is truncation happen from source to reception.

Answer (score 3):

By default, when a value is truncated, a warning is logged. If you want to **treat truncation as an error**, select the option `Reject Truncated/Overflowed rows` in the target definition.

If rejecting the problematic rows is not enough, you can **configure the session to fail** by setting the non-fatal error threshold to `1` (option `Stop on errors`).

If you need to **monitor only selected columns**, use the following expression for each of them:

```
out_OneCharColumn = IIF(LEN(in_OneCharColumn) > 1
                      , ABORT('Source value would be truncated')
                      , in_OneCharColumn)
```

More information: [How to Use Error Handling Options and Techniques in Informatica PowerCenter](http://www.disoln.org/2014/04/Error-Handling-Options-and-Techniques-in-Informatica-PowerCenter.html)

Comment: but what if I have a lot of column do I need to specify all of them?? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you can't monitor it using expression as it's getting truncated in Source.

Comment: @NavjotBhardwaj That depends on the source definition. My understanding is that the OP has a `char(longer than 1)` column in the source and a `char(1)` column in the target, so it's the latter that truncates the values.

Comment: @Marek Just read the problem statement again and you're right mate.